# Recursive Directory Creation in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I'm dabbling with Python 2.7, using it to script an environment setup. I'm supplying a text file to my script which contains a list of directories which it should check for and create if they don't exist.

I have the main mechanism working, but there seems to be an odd behaviour when I create the directory that doesn't exist. The piece of code is:

```
def checkPaths(fileArray):
#fileArray is an array of file paths as strings
    for item in fileArray:
        print item
        if os.path.exists(item):
            print '\t path exists for item'
        else:
            response = raw_input('\t path does not exist for item. \n\tDo you want to create it? [y/n]: ')
            type(response.lower())
            if response == 'y':
                print 'Making new dir'
                parseAndBuildPath(item)
            elif response == 'n':
                print 'Not making new dir'
                continue
            else:
                print 'Response not recognised'
                exit(0)

def parseAndBuildPath(filePath):
    splitFilePath = filePath.split(_SEPARATOR)
    #Find out which parts of the supplied path don't exist and create them...
    recursiveFileCheck(splitFilePath, 0, '')
    return

def recursiveFileCheck(splitFilePath, arrayIndex, currentState):
print ''
if arrayIndex < len(splitFilePath):
    #Follow on from parseAndBuildPath, recursively check the split path. If it doesn't exist, create it and iterate
    #Split file path is an array, arrayIndex is int

    #Check the current state of recursion
    if currentState == '':
        #For the first iteration, don't add a separator
        currentState = currentState+splitFilePath[arrayIndex]
    else:
        #All other times, add the separator
        currentState = currentState+_SEPARATOR+splitFilePath[arrayIndex]

    if not os.path.exists(currentState):
            print 'Current state before creation is '+currentState
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(currentState))
    else:
        print currentState + " exists. Not creating new dir..."

    arrayIndex = arrayIndex+1
    recursiveFileCheck(splitFilePath, arrayIndex, currentState)
else:
    print "Finished recursive check. Returning."
    return
```

As you can see, my if statement is detecting whether the `currentState` (which is a file path) exists. If not, it tries to make the directory. Every time it runs, it hits the exception saying the path already exists, but stops one directory short of the target directory. For example

```
Checking for C:\Users\Donglecow\Documents\Python\FOO\BAR\
     path does not exist for item. 
Do you want to create it? [y/n]: y
Making new dir
Skipping creation of C:\Users\Donglecow\Documents\Python\FOO because it already exists.
```

When it detects that a directory doesn't exist, it fails when creating the directory because one of the parent directories exists, yet the `currentState` variable is accurate.

```
Current state before creation is C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Python\FOO
...
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\Donglecow\\Documents\\Python'
```

Comment: try to raise (or log) the exception that occurs in the `os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(currentState))` block

Comment: Thanks for that. I've noticed I probably don't need an exception, as it just needs to carry on if the exception would be hit, so I've just included it in the if statement. I've edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: Did you try to add a Windows separator at the end of the currentState variable because it is the only "incorrect" thing I see ?

Comment: I am doing that in the code, but it doesn't seem to apply it properly when it creates the directories. I changed it and ran it again, and now it works. Thanks for the pointer! If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Code change for reference (I know comments wreck the formatting so I'll add this to the answer):        `if not os.path.exists(currentState):
                currentState = currentState+_SEPARATOR
                print 'Current state before creation is '+currentState
                os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(currentState))`